# How to align two svg masked images on the same line

Tags: css, svg

I have an svg mask and the mask works perfectly on any image in chrome but it does not allow me to align two images . When I align two images and apply the mask, it only displays 1 image and when i write a text before the image, the text hides the image.

This is my svg code

```
<svg width="0" height="0">
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="shape">
            <path transform="translate(0.000000,163.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)" d="M373 1197 c-355 -355 -363 -363 -363 -402 0 -39 8 -47 363 -402 355
-355 363 -363 402 -363 39 0 47 8 402 363 355 355 363 363 363 402 0 39 -8 47
-363 402 -355 355 -363 363 -402 363 -39 0 -47 -8 -402 -363z" />
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
</svg>


<img class='photo_rectangle_inverse' src='http://i.imgur.com/NR6kefg.jpg' />

<img class='photo_rectangle_inverse' src='http://i.imgur.com/DXaH323.jpg' />
```

And here is my css code

```
.photo_rectangle_inverse {
    height:160px;
    width:170px;
    -webkit-clip-path: url(#shape);
    clip-path: url(#shape);
}
```

So this is supposed to display two images but it only displays one like this

[image]

But it is normally supposed to display the mask on the two images

```
<img class='photo_rectangle_inverse' src='http://i.imgur.com/NR6kefg.jpg' />

    <img class='photo_rectangle_inverse' src='http://i.imgur.com/DXaH323.jpg' />
```

Here is a **[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manofgod/vxum7dnn/1/)**

**How to dispaly and align those two svg masked images on the same line ?**
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the SVG `translate()` functionality which moves a shape. This is causing the shape to not always be in exactly the right place every time.

What you need to do to fix this is to add a piece of CSS to help sort out the position. that being `-webkit-transform:translateZ(1px);`

```css
.photo_rectangle_inverse {
  height: 160px;
  width: 170px;
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#shape);
  clip-path: url(#shape);
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(1px)
}
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="shape">
      <path transform="translate(0.000000,163.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)" d="M373 1197 c-355 -355 -363 -363 -363 -402 0 -39 8 -47 363 -402 355
-355 363 -363 402 -363 39 0 47 8 402 363 355 355 363 363 363 402 0 39 -8 47
-363 402 -355 355 -363 363 -402 363 -39 0 -47 -8 -402 -363z" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>


<img class='photo_rectangle_inverse' src='http://i.imgur.com/NR6kefg.jpg' />

<img class='photo_rectangle_inverse' src='http://i.imgur.com/DXaH323.jpg' />
```

I would also look into cleaning up the SVG path, it seems way to overly filled up considering the simplicity of the shape. I've made this myself and results in near enough the exact same outcome but with a lot less code.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.photo_rectangle_inverse {
  height: 160px;
  width: 170px;
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#shape);
  clip-path: url(#shape);
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(1px)
}
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0" viewBox="0 0 160 160">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="shape">
      <path d="M10,70 Q0,80 10,90 L70,150 Q80,160 90,150 L150,90 Q160,80 150,70 L90,10 Q80,0 70,10z" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>


<img class='photo_rectangle_inverse' src='http://i.imgur.com/NR6kefg.jpg' />

<img class='photo_rectangle_inverse' src='http://i.imgur.com/DXaH323.jpg' />
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks for that.